# Populating using object array and filtering cascade dropdown lists using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, drop-down-menu

I have three dropdowns that I need to populate using an object array:

HTML:

```
<select id="crop"></select>
<select id="type"></select>
<select id="practice"></select>
```

Data (it is much larger):

```
var crops = [{
"Crop": "Annual Forage ",
    "Type": " No Type Specified ",
    "Practice": " Dec - Jan Index Interval",
    "CropCode": 0332
}, {
"Crop": "Annual Forage ",
    "Type": " No Type Specified ",
    "Practice": " Feb - Mar Index Interval",
    "CropCode": 0332
 }, {
"Crop": "Annual Forage ",
    "Type": " No Type Specified ",
    "Practice": " Jan - Feb Index Interval",
    "CropCode": 0332
 }, {
"Crop": "Apiculture ",
    "Type": " No Type Specified ",
    "Practice": " Jun - Jul Index Interval",
    "CropCode": 1191
 }, {
"Crop": "Apiculture ",
    "Type": " No Type Specified ",
    "Practice": " Jan - Feb Index Interval",
    "CropCode": 1191
 }, {
"Crop": "Apiculture ",
    "Type": " No Type Specified ",
    "Practice": " Mar - Apr Index Interval",
    "CropCode": 1191
  }, {
"Crop": "Apiculture ",
    "Type": " No Type Specified ",
    "Practice": " Sep - Oct Index Interval",
    "CropCode": 1191
 }, {
"Crop": "Apples",
    "Type": " Processing",
    "Practice": " Irrigated",
    "CropCode": 0054
 }, {
"Crop": "Apples",
    "Type": " Processing ",
    "Practice": " Non-Irrigated",
    "CropCode": 0054
 }, {
"Crop": "Apples ",
    "Type": " Processing ",
    "Practice": " Non-Irrigated(Oc)",
    "CropCode": 0054
 }, {
"Crop": "Barley ",
    "Type": " Spring Malting ",
    "Practice": " Irrigated",
    "CropCode": 0091
 }];
```

First I eliminate the `Crop` that is a duplicate, and then populate the first dropdown:

```
var options = unique(crops, "Crop");
var selectOptions = '';

for (i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {

selectOptions += '<option value="' + options[i] + '">' + options[i] + '</option>';
}
$('#crop').append(selectOptions).on('change', function () {
});

//Eliminates duplicates
function unique(list, attr) {
var result = [];
$.each(list, function (i, e) {
    if ($.inArray(e[attr], result) == -1) result.push(e[attr]);
});
return result;
}
```

So far this works just fine, but then I need to populate the second drop down with the correspondent `Type` and the third with its respective `Practice`. I'm stuck here, and I can't get it to do it. I need that when a selection is made in the firt drop down, let's say: "Apiculture", only the `Type` and `Practice` for "Apiculture" populate the second and third dropdowns. Thanks in advance.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/emfuentes27/bsvjk72v/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can iterate over [**`each`**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) `crop` object and check if the `crop` matches the value of the drop down, and if it does, populate the other two dropdowns accordingly:

```
$('#crop').append(selectOptions).on('change', function () {
    var selected = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
    $('#type, #practice').empty();
    $.each(crops, function(i, v) {
        if (v.Crop == selected) {
            $('#type').append('<option value="'+v.Type+'">'+v.Type+'</option>');
            $('#practice').append('<option value="'+v.Practice+'">'+v.Practice+'</option>');
        }
    });
});
```

[**Example Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bsvjk72v/6/)